# How to invoke a system call via syscall or sysenter in inline assembly?

Tags: linux, gcc, x86, system-calls, inline-assembly

How can we implement the system call using sysenter/syscall directly in x86 Linux? Can anybody provide help? It would be even better if you can also show the code for amd64 platform.

I know in x86, we can use

```
__asm__(
"               movl $1, %eax  \n"
"               movl $0, %ebx \n"
"               call *%gs:0x10 \n"
);
```

to route to sysenter indirectly.

But how can we code using sysenter/syscall directly to issue a system call?

I find some material http://damocles.blogbus.com/tag/sysenter/ . But still find it difficult to figure out.

Comment: [How to access the system call from user-space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11609110/608639), [How to invoke a system call via sysenter in inline assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9506353/608639), [Linux system call table or cheetsheet in assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3614995/608639), [Assembly and System Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1773249/608639), [What does “int 0x80” mean in assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1817577/608639), etc.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First of all, **you can't safely use GNU C Basic `asm("");` syntax for this** (without input/output/clobber constraints).  You need Extended asm to tell the compiler about registers you modify.  See the [inline asm in the GNU C manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) and the [inline-assembly tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info) for links to other guides for details on what things like `"D"(1)` means as part of an `asm()` statement.

You also need `asm volatile` because that's not implicit for Extended `asm` statements with 1 or more output operands.

---

I'm going to show you how to execute system calls by writing a program that writes `Hello World!` to standard output by using the `write()` system call. Here's the source of the program without an implementation of the actual system call :

```
#include <sys/types.h>

ssize_t my_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t size);

int main(void)
{
    const char hello[] = "Hello world!\n";
    my_write(1, hello, sizeof(hello));
    return 0;
}
```

You can see that I named my custom system call function as `my_write` in order to avoid name clashes with the "normal" `write`, provided by libc. The rest of this answer contains the source of `my_write` for i386 and amd64.

### i386

System calls in i386 Linux are implemented using the 128th interrupt vector, e.g. by calling `int 0x80` in your assembly code, having set the parameters accordingly beforehand, of course. It is possible to do the same via `SYSENTER`, but actually executing this instruction is achieved by the VDSO virtually mapped to each running process. Since `SYSENTER` was never meant as a direct replacement of the `int 0x80` API, it's never directly executed by userland applications - instead, when an application needs to access some kernel code, it calls the virtually mapped routine in the VDSO (that's what the `call *%gs:0x10` in your code is for), which contains all the code supporting the `SYSENTER` instruction. There's quite a lot of it because of how the instruction actually works.

If you want to read more about this, have a look at [this link](http://articles.manugarg.com/systemcallinlinux2_6.html). It contains a fairly brief overview of the techniques applied in the kernel and the VDSO.  See also [The Definitive Guide to (x86) Linux System Calls](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/#virtual-system-calls) - some system calls like `getpid` and `clock_gettime` are so simple the kernel can export code + data that runs in user-space so the VDSO never needs to enter the kernel, making it much faster even than `sysenter` could be.

---

**It's much easier to use the slower `int $0x80` to invoke the 32-bit ABI.**

```
// i386 Linux
#include <asm/unistd.h>      // compile with -m32 for 32 bit call numbers
//#define __NR_write 4
ssize_t my_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t size)
{
    ssize_t ret;
    asm volatile
    (
        "int $0x80"
        : "=a" (ret)
        : "0"(__NR_write), "b"(fd), "c"(buf), "d"(size)
        : "memory"    // the kernel dereferences pointer args
    );
    return ret;
}
```

As you can see, using the `int 0x80` API is relatively simple. The number of the syscall goes to the `eax` register, while all the parameters needed for the syscall go into respectively `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`, `esi`, `edi`, and `ebp`. System call numbers can be obtained by reading the file `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h`.

Prototypes and descriptions of the functions are available in the 2nd section of the manual, so in this case `write(2)`.

The kernel saves/restores all the registers (except EAX) so we can use them as input-only operands to the inline asm.  See [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6)

Keep in mind that the clobber list also contains the `memory` parameter, which means that the instruction listed in the instruction list references memory (via the `buf` parameter).  (A pointer input to inline asm does not imply that the pointed-to memory is also an input.  See [How can I indicate that the memory *pointed* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432259/how-can-i-indicate-that-the-memory-pointed-to-by-an-inline-asm-argument-may-be))

### amd64

Things look different on the AMD64 architecture which sports a new instruction called `SYSCALL`. It is very different from the original `SYSENTER` instruction, and definitely much easier to use from userland applications - it really resembles a normal `CALL`, actually, and adapting the old `int 0x80` to the new `SYSCALL` is pretty much trivial.  (Except it uses RCX and R11 instead of the kernel stack to save the user-space RIP and RFLAGS so the kernel knows where to return).

In this case, the number of the system call is still passed in the register `rax`, but the registers used to hold the arguments now nearly match the function calling convention: `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `r10`, `r8` and `r9` in that order.  (`syscall` itself destroys `rcx` [so `r10` is used instead of `rcx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676657/why-assembly-x86-64-syscall-parameters-are-not-in-alphabetical-order-like-i386), letting libc wrapper functions just use `mov r10, rcx` / `syscall`.)

```
// x86-64 Linux
#include <asm/unistd.h>      // compile without -m32 for 64 bit call numbers
// #define __NR_write 1
ssize_t my_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t size)
{
    ssize_t ret;
    asm volatile
    (
        "syscall"
        : "=a" (ret)
        //                 EDI      RSI       RDX
        : "0"(__NR_write), "D"(fd), "S"(buf), "d"(size)
        : "rcx", "r11", "memory"
    );
    return ret;
}
```

(See it compile on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,source:%27%23include+%3Csys/types.h%3E+++++++//+ssize_t%0A%23include+%3Casm/unistd.h%3E++++++//+compile+without+-m32+for+64+bit+call+numbers%0A//+%23define+__NR_write+1%0A%0A%23if+defined(__x86_64__)+%26%26+defined(__linux__)%0Assize_t+my_write(int+fd,+const+void+*buf,+size_t+size)%0A%7B%0A++++ssize_t+ret%3B%0A++++asm+volatile%0A++++(%0A++++++++%22syscall%22%0A++++++++:+%22%3Da%22+(ret)%0A++++++++:+%220%22(__NR_write),+%22D%22(fd),+%22S%22(buf),+%22d%22(size)%0A++++++++:+%22rcx%22,+%22r11%22,+%22memory%22%0A++++)%3B%0A++++return+ret%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:51.952226370925146,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg92,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:48.047773629074854,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))

Do notice how practically the only thing that needed changing were the register names, and the actual instruction used for making the call. This is mostly thanks to the input/output lists provided by gcc's extended inline assembly syntax, which automagically provides appropriate move instructions needed for executing the instruction list.

The `"0"(callnum)` matching constraint could be written as `"a"` because operand 0 (the `"=a"(ret)` output) only has one register to pick from; we know it will pick EAX.  Use whichever you find more clear.

---

Note that non-Linux OSes, like MacOS, use different call numbers.  And even different arg-passing conventions for 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that it very unlikely for even weird programmer to directly code using sysenter to invoke a system calls. We are actually working on a binary (including malware) analyzer for listing all the system calls in a target program. That is why we want to collect all the ways a system call is issued. It seems that we can ignore this direct sysenter approach.

Comment: Why is the first input argument is "0", shouldn't it be "a" as the system call number goes into eax/rax?

Comment: @Calmarius : the `0` here means "the first output argument". AFAIR (this was a long time ago), the particular version of gcc that I used to compile this for some reason rejected the - one would think - perfectly valid `"a"(__NR_write)` here. gcc 6.1.1 doesn't have a problem with that, so I guess you can use it.

Comment: According to http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S?v=3.14#L37 , to need to specify `"cc"` (because eflags are saved) or `"edi"` or `"esi"` (because these registers are also saved) in the clobbers list.

Comment: @pls : On the x86 targets `cc` clobber doesn't do anything. You can change the flags in the inline assembly and no harm will be done to the surrounding _C_ code. Other targets (not Intel) require `cc` clobbers. For consistency 
 and documentation more than anything it's not a bad idea to list `cc` as a clobber if the flags do change.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Right, but it's *not* good documentation in this case because the Linux system-call ABIs preserve EFLAGS (and `edi` / `esi`).  Daniel: you could also avoid the `"memory"` clobber with a dummy memory input (cast to a struct or array) to tell the compiler that it will read `length` bytes from `buf`, like the example in the manual https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html: `"m" (*(const char (*)[length]) buf)`

Comment: @Infinite: right, the kernel developers don't want people to use `sysenter` directly, so they can change it's ABI (as far as the "dance" that user-space and the kernel do to pass a return address to the kernel).

Comment: @PeterCordes and Daniel, I was playing around with an explicit register version https://stackoverflow.com/a/54956854/895245 , and noticed that `"D"` does not seem to extend `fd` to a quad. Do you think there is a missing `int64_t` cast here, or do you understand why the cast is not necessary? Cheers.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功: Why would it?  The input is an `int`, which means the upper 32 bits of the register are unused by the asm.  It would be a missed optimization if it wasted an instruction zero or sign-extending narrow inputs without asking for it.  The system-call arg is declared as `int`, so you can safely count on the kernel to ignore such garbage, too.

Answer (score 5):

**Explicit register variables**

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Explicit-Register-Variables.html#Explicit-Reg-Vars)

I believe this should now generally be the recommended approach over register constraints because:

- it can represent all registers, including `r8`, `r9` and `r10` which are used for system call arguments: [How to specify register constraints on the Intel x86_64 register r8 to r15 in GCC inline assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159551/how-to-specify-register-constraints-on-the-intel-x86-64-register-r8-to-r15-in-gc)
- it's the only optimal option for other ISAs besides x86 like ARM, which don't have the magic register constraint names: [How to specify an individual register as constraint in ARM GCC inline assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929442/how-to-specify-an-individual-register-as-constraint-in-arm-gcc-inline-assembly/54845046#54845046) (besides using a temporary register + clobbers + and an extra mov instruction)
- I'll argue that this syntax is more readable than using the single letter mnemonics such as `S -> rsi`

Register variables are used for example in glibc 2.29, see: [`sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h;h=b88c46b589fe314b32a28e5d4232bdccfc9fbef0;hb=56c86f5dd516284558e106d04b92875d5b623b7a#l284).

main_reg.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

ssize_t my_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t size) {
    register int64_t rax __asm__ ("rax") = 1;
    register int rdi __asm__ ("rdi") = fd;
    register const void *rsi __asm__ ("rsi") = buf;
    register size_t rdx __asm__ ("rdx") = size;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "syscall"
        : "+r" (rax)
        : "r" (rdi), "r" (rsi), "r" (rdx)
        : "rcx", "r11", "memory"
    );
    return rax;
}

void my_exit(int exit_status) {
    register int64_t rax __asm__ ("rax") = 60;
    register int rdi __asm__ ("rdi") = exit_status;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "syscall"
        : "+r" (rax)
        : "r" (rdi)
        : "rcx", "r11", "memory"
    );
}

void _start(void) {
    char msg[] = "hello world\n";
    my_exit(my_write(1, msg, sizeof(msg)) != sizeof(msg));
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-assembly-cheat/blob/4102316f1b923f6cd98eca11cc5584afd4184139/x86-64/c/linux/hello_regvar.c).

Compile and run:

```
gcc -O3 -std=c99 -ggdb3 -ffreestanding -nostdlib -Wall -Werror \
  -pedantic -o main_reg.out main_reg.c
./main.out
echo $?
```

Output

```
hello world
0
```

For comparison, the following analogous to [How to invoke a system call via syscall or sysenter in inline assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506353/how-to-invoke-a-system-call-via-sysenter-in-inline-assembly/9508738#9508738) produces equivalent assembly:

main_constraint.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

ssize_t my_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t size) {
    ssize_t ret;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "syscall"
        : "=a" (ret)
        : "0" (1), "D" (fd), "S" (buf), "d" (size)
        : "rcx", "r11", "memory"
    );
    return ret;
}

void my_exit(int exit_status) {
    ssize_t ret;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "syscall"
        : "=a" (ret)
        : "0" (60), "D" (exit_status)
        : "rcx", "r11", "memory"
    );
}

void _start(void) {
    char msg[] = "hello world\n";
    my_exit(my_write(1, msg, sizeof(msg)) != sizeof(msg));
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-assembly-cheat/blob/4102316f1b923f6cd98eca11cc5584afd4184139/x86-64/c/linux/hello.c).

Disassembly of both with:

```
objdump -d main_reg.out
```

is almost identical, here is the `main_reg.c` one:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001000 <my_write>:
    1000:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
    1005:   0f 05                   syscall 
    1007:   c3                      retq   
    1008:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    100f:   00 

0000000000001010 <my_exit>:
    1010:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
    1015:   0f 05                   syscall 
    1017:   c3                      retq   
    1018:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    101f:   00 

0000000000001020 <_start>:
    1020:   c6 44 24 ff 00          movb   $0x0,-0x1(%rsp)
    1025:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
    102a:   48 8d 74 24 f3          lea    -0xd(%rsp),%rsi
    102f:   48 b8 68 65 6c 6c 6f    movabs $0x6f77206f6c6c6568,%rax
    1036:   20 77 6f 
    1039:   48 89 44 24 f3          mov    %rax,-0xd(%rsp)
    103e:   ba 0d 00 00 00          mov    $0xd,%edx
    1043:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
    1048:   c7 44 24 fb 72 6c 64    movl   $0xa646c72,-0x5(%rsp)
    104f:   0a 
    1050:   0f 05                   syscall 
    1052:   31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
    1054:   48 83 f8 0d             cmp    $0xd,%rax
    1058:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
    105d:   40 0f 95 c7             setne  %dil
    1061:   0f 05                   syscall 
    1063:   c3                      retq
```

So we see that GCC inlined those tiny syscall functions as would be desired.

`my_write` and `my_exit` are the same for both, but `_start` in `main_constraint.c` is slightly different:

```
0000000000001020 <_start>:
    1020:   c6 44 24 ff 00          movb   $0x0,-0x1(%rsp)
    1025:   48 8d 74 24 f3          lea    -0xd(%rsp),%rsi
    102a:   ba 0d 00 00 00          mov    $0xd,%edx
    102f:   48 b8 68 65 6c 6c 6f    movabs $0x6f77206f6c6c6568,%rax
    1036:   20 77 6f 
    1039:   48 89 44 24 f3          mov    %rax,-0xd(%rsp)
    103e:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
    1043:   c7 44 24 fb 72 6c 64    movl   $0xa646c72,-0x5(%rsp)
    104a:   0a 
    104b:   89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
    104d:   0f 05                   syscall 
    104f:   31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
    1051:   48 83 f8 0d             cmp    $0xd,%rax
    1055:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
    105a:   40 0f 95 c7             setne  %dil
    105e:   0f 05                   syscall 
    1060:   c3                      retq
```

It is interesting to observe that in this case GCC found a slightly shorter equivalent encoding by picking:

```
    104b:   89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
```

to set the `fd` to `1`, which equals the `1` from the syscall number, rather than a more direct:

```
    1025:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
```

For an in-depth discussion of the calling conventions, see also: [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6)

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, GCC 8.2.0.

Comment: The casts are unnecessary.  The system-call args that are declared as `int` will safely to ignore high garbage in the register in the kernel.  And BTW, register asm is the only way to specify a specific one of r8..r15.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah awesome, mentioned about `r8` - `r10`.

Comment: If you're using TCC, you might want to avoid using explicit register variables - my syscalls weren't working until I changed it (but they did work with gcc).

Comment: Also, Linux system calls specifically *don't* clobber RFLAGS, so a `"cc"` clobber is inappropriate here.  (It's implicit anyway, so there's no performance to be gained by removing it.)