# With gcc inline assembly can you set %r# registers as input constraints?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly

I have this function:

```
#include <cstdint>

using ::std::intptr_t;

struct syscall_param {
   syscall_param(intptr_t v) : value(v) { }
   syscall_param(void *v) : value(reinterpret_cast<::std::intptr_t>(v)) { }
   intptr_t value;
};

inline intptr_t do_syscall(syscall_param const &callnum,
                           syscall_param const &p1,
                           syscall_param const &p2,
                           syscall_param const &p3,
                           syscall_param const &p4,
                           syscall_param const &p5,
                           syscall_param const &p6)
{
   intptr_t retval;
   asm volatile (
      "movq %5, %%r10\n\t"
      "movq %6, %%r8\n\t"
      "movq %7, %%r9\n\t"
      "syscall\n\t"
       :"=a"(retval)
       :"a"(callnum.value), "D"(p1.value), "S"(p2.value), "d"(p3.value), "g"(p4.value), "g"(p5.value), "g"(p6.value)
       :"%rcx", "%r11", "%r10", "%r8", "%r9"
      );
   return retval;
}
```

I would really like to get rid of the `movq` instructions by using contraints. While I can use constraints to get things into the `rax`, `edi`, `esi`, and `rdx` registers, there don't seem to be any constraints that let me get things into the `r10`, `r8`, and `r9` registers. It seems like there ought to be a constrain that would allow me to get things into an arbitrary `r#` register. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: Yes you can use [Local Register Variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html)

Comment: You will also want to use a `memory` clobber because it appears you could be passing addresses through registers rather than memory constraints.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - Local register variables do not appear to have the desired effect. https://godbolt.org/z/SzQZnS - Also, what's a memory clobber?

Comment: @MichaelPetch - I think I figured out how to make the local register variables work for me: https://godbolt.org/z/saNrAo - that just leaves the memory clobber.

Comment: 2 of the the linked duplicates show correct syscall wrappers with `"memory"` in the clobber list, e.g. [How to specify register constraints on the Intel x86\_64 register r8 to r15 in GCC inline assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31774784).  Docs for "memory" clobber: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html.  See also [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56432259) for why this is a problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Thanks! I got it. I maybe should've searched harder for those answers, but I didn't find them on a first googling.