# Using __kernel_vsyscall to call write system call not working

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, vdso

I wrote a sample program to use `__kernel_vsyscall` for system call

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/auxv.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long sysinfo = getauxval(AT_SYSINFO);
    unsigned long syscall_num = 1;  // 1 is system call number for exit
    long exit_status = 42;

    asm ("movl %0, %%eax\n"
            "movl %1, %%ebx\n"
            "call *%2"
            :
            :"m" (syscall_num), "m" (exit_status), "m" (sysinfo)
            :"eax", "ebx");

    printf("sysinfo:%lx\n", sysinfo);
    return 0;
}
```

This code which calls `exit(42)` works fine.

```
$gcc userprog.c -o userprog -m32
$ ./userprog 
$ echo $?
42
```

But when I tried to call `write(1, "hello world", 12)`, it failed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/auxv.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long sysinfo = getauxval(AT_SYSINFO);
    unsigned long syscall_num = 4;  // 4 is system call number for write
    char buffer[] = "hello world";
        int buffer_length = sizeof(buffer); 

    asm ("movl %0, %%eax\n"
            "movl %1, %%ebx\n"
            "movl %2, %%ecx\n"
            "movl %3, %%edx\n"
            "call *%2"
            :
            :"m" (syscall_num), "i"(1), "m" (buffer), "m"(buffer_length)
            :"eax", "ebx", "ecx");

    printf("sysinfo:%lx\n", sysinfo);
    return 0;
}
```

It fails with segmentation fault.

dmesg:

```
[43453.401815] userprog[13528]: segfault at 6c6c6568 ip 000000006c6c6568 sp 00000000ffc647ac error 14 in libc-2.27.so[f7cf3000+1d2000]
[43453.401821] Code: Bad RIP value.
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506353/how-to-invoke-a-system-call-via-sysenter-in-inline-assembly/54956854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `"call *%2"` in your inline assembly seems wrong. And you can check this out in `gdb` quite easily:

```
(gdb) layout asm
(gdb) break main
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x5eb: file test.c, line 31.
(gdb) run
```

The code generated from the inline asm looks like this for me:

```
0x5655562b <main+94>    mov    -0x34(%ebp),%eax
0x5655562e <main+97>    mov    $0x1,%ebx
0x56555633 <main+102>   mov    -0x28(%ebp),%ecx
0x56555636 <main+105>   mov    -0x30(%ebp),%edx
0x56555639 <main+108>   call   *-0x28(%ebp)
```

Break at the call address:

```
(gdb) break *0x56555639
(gdb) c
(gdb) si
Cannot access memory at address 0x6c6c6568)
```

I think your assembly should look something like this:

```
asm ("movl %0, %%eax\n"
     "movl %1, %%ebx\n"
     "movl %2, %%ecx\n"
     "movl %3, %%edx\n"
     "call *%4"
     :
     :"m" (syscall_num), "i"(1), "m" (buffer), "m"(buffer_length), "m"(sysinfo)
     :"eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx");
```

Please note you were also missing `edx` in your clobber list.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. But this does nor print "hello world" on the screen. Anything more is missing

Comment: Right. Well, replacing `"m"(buffer)` with `"r"(buffer)` also fixed that for me ...

Comment: May i know the reason for replacing "m" with "r"

Comment: I must admit I'm not so well trained in this kind of stuff, but with your original asm code, `ecx` was being set up to `0x6c6c6568` which stands for the `hell` part of the string, so the value instead of it's address. "r" simply fixed that and initialized `ecx` to the string address on the stack.