# Printing into the terminal without printf?

Tags: c, linux, unix, output, system-calls

I want to write a C program that prints out the content of a file in  into the terminal.

However, we are not allowed to use the `<stdio.h>` library, so functions like `printf` aren't available.

What are the alternative ways to print things into the terminal?

I was doing some searching but I couldn't find a direct answer as most people simply use `printf`.

Comment: Also this should help [How to invoke a system cal -via sysenter in inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506353/how-to-invoke-a-system-call-via-sysenter-in-inline-assembly)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `write`

https://linux.die.net/man/2/write

Example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char my_string[] = "Hello, World!\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, my_string, strlen(my_string));
}
```

> For my uni assignment, I am to write a C program that prints out the content of a file in Linux/Unix **into the terminal.**

You cannot really "write into the terminal". What you can do is to write to stdout and stderr, and then the terminal will handle it after that.

EDIT:

Well, as KamilCuk mentioned in comments, you can write to the terminal `/dev/tty`. Here is an example:

```
#include <fcntl.h>  // open
#include <unistd.h> // write
#include <string.h> // strlen
#include <stdlib.h> // EXIT_FAILURE

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("/dev/tty", O_WRONLY);

    if(fd == -1) {
        char error_msg[] = "Error opening tty";
        write(STDERR_FILENO, error_msg, strlen(error_msg));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char my_string[] = "Hello, World!\n";
    write(fd, my_string, strlen(my_string));
}
```

Comment: From what i understand, this writes it into the file. does it print it out to the terminal as well?

Comment: @secondaryaccount It writes it to standard output

Comment: Nitpicking: `You cannot really "write into the terminal"` Well, you can write to `/dev/tty`, and `/dev/tty` is the "controlling terminal", so writing to `/dev/tty` would be like writing into a terminal