# Using asm in C code and compiling without -no-pie option

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, position-independent-code

My simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char argmore[]="Hello world";
int main ( int argc , char** argv) {
    /////// printf 
    asm ("movq $1, %rax\n"
         "movq $1, %rdi\n"
         "movq $argmore, %rsi\n"
         "movq $11, %rdx\n"
         "syscall");
    /////// exit
    asm ("movq $60, %rax\n"
         "movq $1, %rdi\n"
         "syscall");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program as:

```
gcc -no-pie -o test test.c
```

It works correctly, prints "hello word" and exits successfully. But when I compile it as:

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

I receive this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjSTY9T.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against undefined symbol `argmore' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't want to compile my program with `-no-pie` option. What should I do? How can I change my program to compile correctly without `-no-pie` option?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ when the code and compiler are C?

Comment: Have you tried `gcc -o test -fPIE test.c` as suggested by the linker error message?

Comment: @rturrado yes. i get the same error

Comment: Note that your code is incorrect because you clobber registers without marking them in the clobber list.   I believe a simple `lea argmore(%rip), %rsi` should address the issue you ask about.

Comment: @fuz yeeeeeeeees. it is true. my problem is solved. thank you. thank you. thank you. please send your comment as response so i can give you score

Comment: @taranom No, your problem is not solved.  There are still clobbers missing and your code will fail spectacularly later on.

Comment: To see how to properly make a system call from inline assembly, including safe use of clobbers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506353/how-to-invoke-a-system-call-via-syscall-or-sysenter-in-inline-assembly/9508738#9508738