# GCC promotes weird relocation R_X86_64_32S error but not in manually linking

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm trying to invoke [`sys_write`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/syscalls.h#L499) via the [`syscall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall) instruction under Linux environment on an x86_64 machine with inline assembly in C files. To achieve this, I wrote the following code:

```
[tjm@ArchPad poc]$ cat poc.c 
const char S[] = "abcd\n";

int main() {
    __asm __volatile(" \
            movq $1, %%rax; \
            movq $1, %%rdi; \
            movq %0, %%rsi; \
            movq $5, %%rdx; \
            syscall;"
            :
            : "i"(S)
            );
    return 0;
}
```

While my compiling it with GCC, the following error promoted:

```
[tjm@ArchPad poc]$ gcc -O0 poc.c -o poc
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWYxmSb.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `S' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I added `-fPIE` to the compiler command. Unfortunately, nothing changed:

```
[tjm@ArchPad poc]$ gcc -fPIE -O0 poc.c -o poc 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdK36lx.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `S' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is so weird that it made me curious to compile and link it manually:

```
[tjm@ArchPad poc]$ gcc -fPIE -O0 poc.c -S
[tjm@ArchPad poc]$ as -O0 poc.s -o poc.o
[tjm@ArchPad poc]$ ld -O0 -melf_x86_64 --dynamic-linker /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/crt{1,i,n}.o -lc poc.o -o poc
```

Surprisingly, no error occurred during the attempt above. I then tested the executable's functionality, which seems working:

```
[tjm@ArchPad poc]$ ./poc 
abcd
```

Any ideas of why this happens and how to prevent GCC from promoting the error above?

Comment: `-no-pie`, the opposite of what the message says? Otherwise, maybe don't use "i".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate move instruction `movq $S, %rsi`, despite taking a 64-bit register, takes only a 32-bit signed immediate.  When building a position-independent executable which is to run with [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), as is the default on most Linux systems, your program is typically not located in the low or high 31 bits of virtual memory, so the address of a global or static object like `S` won't fit in a signed 32-bit immediate.

One fix is to use `movabs` instead, which does take a full 64-bit immediate. Replacing `movq %0, %%rsi` with `movabs %0, %%rsi` lets the code build.  However, the better approach is to use RIP-relative addressing `lea S(%rip), %rsi`, which is a shorter instruction and avoids the need for a relocation at load time.  This is a little awkward to do inside inline asm, so you can let the compiler load the address into the register for you, with an input operand like `"S" (S)` (confusingly the constraint for the `rsi` register is `S`, which happens to coincide with the name you chose for your array variable).

When you linked manually, you built a non-position-independent executable, which meant that treating the address as a constant worked.  You can get the same effect by passing `-no-pie` to `gcc`.

There is another serious problem with your code, in that it doesn't declare the registers it clobbers - not only those which you explicitly `mov` into, but also `rcx` and `r11` which `syscall` modifies implicitly.  You should take a look at [How to invoke a system call via syscall or sysenter in inline assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506353/how-to-invoke-a-system-call-via-syscall-or-sysenter-in-inline-assembly/9508738#9508738) which has a correct example.  It would be wise to study those examples carefully - GCC inline asm is powerful, but also very easy to get wrong in subtle ways that the compiler will not help you detect, and which may appear to work in a simple program but fail unpredictably in a more complex one.

Answer (score 0):

GCC supports multiple dialects for the ASM instructions and the default can vary.  Read more here:

```
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm
```

... and of course, the dialects are not compatible with each other.

Comment: This is true, sort of, but does not have anything to do with OP's problem.