# what does size of registers and stack really mean in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new to assembly , and I'm really confused , i read  several articles , and books but i couldn't  understand what does this mean

in assembly x86 we have different  registers each register has specific  size , example

EAX : 32bit

**Q1- Well what does really mean 32bit ? does it mean , i can only store a value of 32bit size ?**

if Yes

**Q2 - If i have very long string how i can mov this string to my register ?**

**Q3 - i want to know exactly  when i should  push and pop from stack ?**

**Q4 i can store my values in my registers without stack ,Why we have a stack ? to solve which problem ?**

if we take example  here is my C code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() 
{
    printf("Hello World");

}
```

Here we pass Hello world to the printf function , and i can pass anythings big or small no matter , if i translate this code to assembly , first things i have to mov system call args to the registers and then call the system call and then int 0x80 . how about if instate of hello world i have a paragraph  ?

**Q5 - also when i mov any data to registers , how i can choose which  register i should mov the data on it ?**

Thanks .

Comment: Read some more, you'll figure it out. Most of what you asked is "not answerable", it's just too confused or based on incorrect premises to do anything with. But yes, `eax` is indeed exactly 32 bits, always. Strings are usually passed referred to by their starting address.

Comment: **Q1**. Yes. **Q2**. Piece by piece if you change it, as a pointer if you pass it around. **Q3**. When ever you need it. E.g. you want to use a register that must be restored at the end: push it, use it, pop it. **Q4**. Yes. We need to store an ubound number of items, interacting always with the last one. Function calls. Paragraph char (?) is not different from 'H' char. **Q5** Make a guess, use the first register that come in mind. As you further develop the code, refine that choice to minimize your target metric (speed, spill/fill, size, complexity).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773249/assembly-and-system-calls/1773277#1773277 re: passing strings by pointer.  I know it's tempting to ask 5 things in one question, but they're not all even related.  e.g. Q5 is nothing to do with the others.  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for lots of info.

Comment: I disagree with the "too broad" close recs. These are pretty sensible questions that a person with only high level language experience will often ask when seeing assembly for the first time, especially the fragmented way it's usually presented in Internet sources. I wouldn't close this question. There are short answers that will get a new assembly programmer over the hump and on to further progress. @JohnBurger did fine.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you'd literally need to write a book in order to address all of the confusion, there are *five different questions* being asked here. The rule is one question per question. This is a textbook case of "too broad" (pardon the pun).

Comment: @Gene: The problem is that multiple questions at once prevent closing this as a duplicate of a question that asks / answers how strings are passed as function or system-call arguments.  There was a discussion on meta not long ago about closing these as a duplicate of one of the things they're asking, and leaving a comment to explain the one question per post rule.  I agree I can understand why someone would be wondering these things, but that doesn't make this a good SO question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registers store numbers. That's it. That's all they do. It's how you, as the programmer, *use* and *interpret* those numbers that makes the program work.

- Each register is 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits in size. They can store either *signed* or *unsigned* numbers - that is, whether their top bit is interpreted as a sign bit, or just as part of the number. Note that those numbers could be the address of a variable in memory - signed-ness isn't a factor then.
- You can add, subtract or do many other things to numbers.
  Put one in one register, another in another, use the `ADD` or `SUB` instruction, and you get a result:

  ```
          MOV  EAX, 0x12345678
          MOV  EBX, 0x12345677
          SUB  EAX, EBX        ; EAX now holds the value 1
  ```
- You can point to values in memory. Store the *address* of a variable in a register, and you can read and write those values:

  ```
          .DATA
  xValue  DD   42       ; Save xValue here

          .CODE
          MOV  EAX, [xValue]         ; Get the current xValue into EAX
          INC  EAX                   ; Add one to it
          MOV  [xValue], EAX         ; Save it back

          INC  [xValue]              ; One line to do the above three

          MOV  EBX, OFFSET xValue    ; Point to xValue with EBX
          MOV  EAX, [EBX]            ; Get the current value
          INC  EAX                   ; Add one to it
          MOV  [EBX], EAX            ; Save it back

          INC DWORD PTR [EBX]        ; One line to do the above three
  ```
- How do you pass strings?
  You don't. You pass the *memory address* of the string, and the receiving function just knows that the value in the register is the address of the string in memory.
- Why do you `PUSH` and `POP` from the stack?

  - There are only a limited number of registers, so to do processes that have a lot of different values you need to store some in memory, swapping values in and out of registers to work on them.
  - You can use reserved areas of memory for each variable; or you can save the values temporarily onto the stack, rather than reserving specific locations in memory for them.
  - Note that if you have a recursive function, having reserved areas of memory won't work - each time through the recursion you need new memory for the next iteration. The stack is perfect for this.
  - Some functions expect their parameters to be stored on the stack, rather than in global variables.
- How do you know which register to use?
  It depends:

  - If you're writing the code, you can use any registers you like - except `SP`/`ESP`/`RSP`, which is reserved for pointing to the stack!

    - There are some architecture conventions:

      - If you're going to use the `REP` or `LOOP` instructions, then you need to use `CX`/`ECX`/`RCX` to hold the count;
      - If you're going to use the `LODS`, `STOS`, `CMPS` and `MOVS` instructions, then you need to use `AL`/`AX`/`EAX`/`RAX`, `SI`/`ESI`/`RSI` and/or `DI`/`EDI`/`RDI`.
    - There are some historic conventions, but these are no longer necessary in 32- and 64-bit programming:

      - `BX`, `SI`, `DI` and `BP` were the only registers that could index memory, so that's what they were used for;
  - If you didn't write the code that you're calling, then it should specify (or use a common standard) which registers hold which parameters, and which register(s) it uses for the return value(s).

Comment: You  are really amazing  , Thank you . the picture  become clear for me now .